# Maximum sum in a torus

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve the following dynamic programming question on uva online judge:

> A grid that wraps both horizontally and vertically is called a torus.
>   Given a torus where each cell contains an integer, determine the
>   sub-rectangle with the largest sum. The sum of a sub-rectangle is the
>   sum of all the elements in that rectangle. The grid below shows a
>   torus where the maximum sub-rectangle has been shaded.

[image: Image of a torus]

We know that there exists a very similar and simpler problem: the maximal sub-rectangle problem where the grid canot wrap. For the simpler variant, we can first take the cumulative of each row and then apply kadane's algorithm in 2 for-loops to solve the problem. For this problem, this is impossible since the grid can now wrap around.

I already have a headstart on this problem by mirroring the matrix 4 times to simulate the rotation of the matrix. However, with all dynamic programming related problems, we have to formulate the recurrence relation. I do not know how to formulate the recurrence for this problem. Could anyone please advise me?

Edit:

I tried using modified kadane's algorithm to search the largest rectangle of at least size 1. However, I am still not getting the right answer. For reference, my code is listed below:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int cc,r,c,R,C,INF = 9999;
    scanf("%d",&cc);
    while(cc--) {
        scanf("%d",&r);
        c = r;
        R = C = 2 * r;
        int l[r][c], sum[R+1][C];
        fill_n(sum[0],C,0);

        for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                scanf("%d",&l[i][j]);
                sum[i+1][j] = l[i][j];
                sum[i+1][c+j] = l[i][j];
                sum[r+i+1][j] = l[i][j];
                sum[r+i+1][c+j] = l[i][j];
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < C; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j < R+1; j++) {
                sum[j][i] += sum[j-1][i];
            }
        }
        int g_max = -INF;
        for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for(int j = i+1; j < i+r+1; j++) {
                int t_max = sum[j][0]-sum[i][0], s = sum[j][0]-sum[i][0], L = 1, lo = 0, hi = 0;
                g_max = max(g_max,t_max);
                for(int k = L; k < C; k++) {
                    s += (sum[j][k]-sum[i][k])-(sum[j][k-L]-sum[i][k-L]);
                    t_max = max(t_max+(sum[j][k]-sum[i][k]),s);
                    if(t_max > g_max) {
                        g_max = t_max;
                        lo = k - L - 1;
                        hi = k;
                        if(hi - lo == c-1) break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n",g_max);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Given this test case:

```
1
5
1 -1 0 0 -4
2 3 -2 -3 2
4 1 -1 5 0
3 -2 1 -3 2
-3 2 4 1 -4
```

The grid in the test case is as shown above. The answer should be 15. But I am getting 24. I am not sure what is wrong with my algorithm since I implemented the kadane's algo from another stackoverflow answer. Is anyone able to help me?

Comment: I assume by mirror you mean copy, and then it actually becomes exactly the same problem as before doesn't it?

Comment: Not really because now I have to do perform kadane's on every single index in the row and column. won't that give me a Time Limit Exceeded error?

Comment: I have added some code to make it easier to see my approach to this problem.

Comment: Well who knows, try it. It's certainly not a naive algorithm though. E: make sure the submatrix is not bigger than n in both directions btw.

Comment: How large can the matrix be?

Comment: The max size of the given matrix is 75 x 75.

Comment: You are saying "take the cumulative of each row and then apply kadane's algorithm in 2 for-loops", which is absolutely correct. What exactly stops you from doing that with your extended rectangle? Do you know how to apply Kadane to a circular 1D array?

Comment: You have an O(nm^2) algorithm, and you propose to double both m and n.  This will slow it down by a constant factor of approximately _____ on large inputs.

Comment: @n.m I will need to have an extra 2 for loops to run kadane's from every cell since I have to consider the rotation as well. Won't that be TLE?

Comment: "I will need to have an extra 2 for loops to run kadane's from every cell since I have to consider the rotation as well." Sorry, this makes no sense. What rotation? Your torus problem is exactly equivalent to the standard subrectangle problem where the source rectangle is repeated twice along each axis and the result subrectangle is restricted in size. You already have the source rectangle repeated twice along each axis. What is left is to apply the standard subrectangle algorithm (modified to restrict the subrectangle size, which doesn't affect complexity). That's O(n^3).

Comment: A naïve O(n^4) algorithm is very simple and doesn't need Kadane at all.

Comment: @n.m. Ok. But once your kadane subrectangle has reached the size restriction, what is the next step? This is what I am confused about.

Comment: If it reached the size restriction, you just stop, because it now encompasses the entire original range of indices and cannot grow any larger.

Comment: @n.m. Ok. Let's say that the size restriction is 5 and my subrectangle indices is from 0 to 4. My algorithm stops here. But don't I have to consider 1 to 0 as well since there is the wrap around?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. You have replicated your rectangle along each axis. This deals perfectly with the wraparound, no further action is needed. Now you are asking how to cope with the wraparound. Why have you replicated the rectangle in the first place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127638/discussion-between-lancehaoh-and-n-m).

Comment: Your overall structure is now good, if you are still having problems you have to debug your code. Try simple test cases, like a 1x1 matrix. Or maybe this 3x3 matrix: 1 10 100 // 1000 10000 100000 // 1000000 10000000 100000000. The result won't be OK but you can learn much from it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a modification of the "Max 2D Range Sum" problem, in which we're given a matrix with it's cells filled with integers. We've to find the maximum possible sum of a sub-rectangle of the matrix. This can be done in `O(n^4)` time.

Here, we can simulate a torus, by making a matrix joining the matrix to itself on right, bottom and on right-bottom. This will make a `2N x 2N` matrix, which can now be taken as a standard input matrix for the "Max 2D Range Sum" problem, with restrictions that the starting row and column can't be beyond the original matrix, and that the ending row and column must differ by atmost `N` rows/columns.

Code:

```
import java.util.* ;
import java.io.BufferedReader ;
import java.io.InputStreamReader ;

public class MaximumSumTorus
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader bro = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)) ;
        int T = Integer.parseInt(bro.readLine().trim()) ;
        for(int t=0;t<T;t++)
        {
            int N = Integer.parseInt(bro.readLine().trim()) ;
            int[][] A = new int[N][N] ;
            for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
            {
                String[] S = bro.readLine().split(" +") ;
                for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
                {
                    A[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(S[j]) ;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(solve(A)) ;
        }
    }
    static int solve(int[][] M)
    {
        int[][] M2 = doubleMatrix(M) ;
        toRangeMatrix(M2) ;
        return(maxInMatrix(M2)) ;
    }
    static int[][] doubleMatrix(int[][] M)
    {
        int[][] M2 = new int[2*M.length][2*M.length] ;
        for(int i=0;i<M.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<M[0].length;j++)
            {
                M2[i][j] = M[i][j] ;
                M2[i+M.length][j] = M[i][j] ;
                M2[i][j+M.length] = M[i][j] ;
                M2[i+M.length][j+M.length] = M[i][j] ;
            }
        }
        return M2 ;
    }
    static void toRangeMatrix(int[][] M)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<M.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<M[0].length;j++)
            {
                if(i>0) M[i][j]+=M[i-1][j] ;
                if(j>0) M[i][j]+=M[i][j-1] ;
                if(i>0 && j>0) M[i][j]-=M[i-1][j-1] ;
            }
        }
    }
    static int maxInMatrix(int[][] M)
    {
        int maxInMatrix = Integer.MIN_VALUE ;
        for(int i=0;i<M.length/2;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<M.length/2;j++)
            {
                for(int k=i;k-i<M.length/2;k++)
                {
                    for(int l=j;l-j<M.length/2;l++)
                    {
                        int subRect = M[k][l] ;
                        if(i>0) subRect -= M[i-1][l] ;
                        if(j>0) subRect -= M[k][j-1] ;
                        if(i>0 && j>0) subRect+=M[i-1][j-1] ;
                        maxInMatrix = Math.max(subRect,maxInMatrix) ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return maxInMatrix ;
    }
}
```